# Does MongoDB supports optimistic locks for bulk operations?

Tags: mongodb, optimistic-locking, bulkupdate, optimistic-concurrency, select-for-update

Does MongoDB support optimistic locks for bulk update operations?
Maybe there is some recipe for how I can handle lost updates for bulk write operations in concurrency?
I tried to use @Version na Queris to update, but it's not working for me.